# SELECT TOP ... FROM UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, union

What is the best way to SELECT TOP N records from UNION of 2 queries?

I can't do

```
SELECT TOP N ... FROM
   (SELECT ... FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT ... FROM Table2)
```

because both queries return huge results I need every bit of optimization possible and would like to avoid returning everything. For the same reason I cannot insert results into #TEMP table first either.

I can't use `SET ROWCOUNT N` either because I may need to group results and this command will limit number of grouped rows, and not underlying row selections.

Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'd `TOP` the subselects as well.

Comment: Why `UNION` ? Do you want to remove duplicate rows ?

Comment: Why can't you do above with `UNION ALL`? I've tested above query on a table with > 100000000 records and the result came immediately.

Comment: But I need top N from summary result, I don't know how many records would come from which query? E.g. if I SELECT TOP 10 and first query has 20 records - second won't even come into play. If, on the other hand, 1st query has 7 records - 2nd query would need to provide additional 3 results.

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlean, I have 2 tables - active log and log archives, users need to perform searches across both.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, is it true? You can have 2 tables, several hundred million of records in each, mixed datatypes (dates, nvarchars, numbers etc.) perform union on both with additional WHERE clauses, use them as a subquery and results comes immediatly?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: No, if you apply `WHERE` and/or `ORDER BY` it'll take it's time. However, the same is true for the sub-queries. If you want N arbitrary records you don't need to use `TOP N` on the sub queries either. If you want N particular records you have to filter/order also the sub queries and order the outer query. Otherwise you might get the wrong result. But i'm not a DBA, so maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: Here's an answer specifically for the case when you select a top 1 from each sub query and you need just one field in the end `SELECT ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 field FROM table1), (SELECT TOP 1 field FROM table2))`. It saves the execution of the second query in a percentage of the cases.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the Top keyword for inner queries also:

```
SELECT TOP N ... FROM
(SELECT TOP N... FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT TOP N... FROM Table2) as result
```

Comment: Actually this I think is exactly what I need. (seeing my comments above) If, for example I requested SELECT TOP 10, and the 1st query has 20 records, it will also be limited by TOP 10, so only its results will be included. If it has, say only 3 records, it will produce only 3 results. Second query will produce another 10 results, giving total of 13, but the outer level TOP 10 will limit it to 10 - 3 from the 1st and 7 from the 2nd. Sorry, thinking aloud :) Thanks @Deepak.Aggrawal

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server requires an alias (e.g. AS UNIONRESULT) for the result set, otherwise it gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following. It uses a CTE which would give you the results of both queries first and then you would select your TOP N from the CTE.

```
WITH table_cte (
(
    [col1],
    [col2],
    ...
)
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT *
    FROM table2
)

SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM table_cte
```

Comment: Thanks, but performance wise this is similar to subqueries - internal queries return all underlying results, which is not optimal

Comment: Orphan parenthesis crashes the example